# How do Yeoman, Grunt and Bower work?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

Following the same model of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1), how would you explain to a 6 year old person how Yeoman, Grunt and Bower works and what are the benefits of using those tools??

Answer (score 3):

Yeoman is a scaffolding tool that uses generators to set up a project or generate additional controllers etc.

Grunt is a task runner that is used to automate tasks when developing your app, such as building it by minifying etc.

Bower is a package-manager specifically for managing the Javascript libraries that will be deployed client-side along with your app.

Comment: My 6 year old would have a lot of questions about this.